# Determining the cosine of the angles between two lines using dot product

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, angles

SCENARIO:I have a certain buffered region (lets say a one way road segment), which will have only one allowed direction represented by vector A. And, there are several other lines which may or may not be in the direction of the road, which are represented by the vector B.

I am trying to find the cosine of the angle between the lines using the cosine(angle)= (A • B) / ||A|| ||B||.

At first, I just wanted to know how to calculate this for one pair of VECTORS A and B. I want to use this to automate the process for the other lines (vector B) in order to find the cosine of the angle.

Is there any tools, so that I can use this ModelBuilder OR is there some code that I can use for the calculation of cosine of the angle?

Answer (score 2):

This function will give you an angle (courtesy of Curtis Price):

```
def get_angle(xy1, xy2):
    arcpy.AddMessage(xy1)
    """Calculate azimuth angle from two points. (Zero is north.)"""
    try:
        # ArcPy point objects
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = xy1.X, xy1.Y, xy2.X, xy2.Y
    except:
        # xy strings, e.g. "0 0"
        if isinstance(xy1, basestring) and isinstance(xy2, basestring):
            xy1, xy2 = xy1.replace('NaN',''), xy2.replace('NaN','')
        x1, y1 = map(float, xy1.split())
        x2, y2 = map(float, xy2.split())
    dx, dy = (x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
    return 90 - math.degrees(math.atan2(dy, dx))
```

where the xy1, and xy2 are [arcpy.Point](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z0000006t000000) objects.

Comment: Does this give angle between two lines ? I am very new to python. Hope I will figure out the way to use this code to use in ArcGIS. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: I should clarify that gets you the angle between two points.